# Use django-summernote without using form?

Tags: django, summernote

I am making a small site with Django. For some reasons, I am not using Django forms to render the forms in templates. I am doing the "traditional" way, by defining `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` etc in the template html files. I want to use django-summernote to enable rich text, especially image uploading, in a textarea. Is it possible to using Use django-summernote without using django.form? If so, how? I have added:

in `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/name/project/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

in urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are not using django forms, there is no need to use `django-summernote`, simply follow the instructions at the [getting started page](http://summernote.org/getting-started/) to integrate it with your template.

Comment: Thanks! But I wanted to use django-summernote mainly because it seems to handle the image upload out of box. Do I need to write the script for the upload otherwise?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to use django forms?

Comment: Thanks Burhan. Yes you are right, I guess it is easier to use django forms. But this brings up another question. How I can add the initial value to the rich text area generated by django-summernote? Thanks!

Comment: Just load the form with an instance (if its a model form) or a dictionary (if its a normal form).

Comment: Could you please explain with more detail? I am using a normal form now. How and where the dictionary should be defined?

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-bound-unbound